# 4th decimal of an infinite sums in R

Tags: r

How to Use iterations to approximate the value of the infinite sum. I need to stop the rounding when the 4th decimal stops changing. How can I create a for loop that has a condition to break this infinite loop?

This is my full question:

**Use iterations to approximate the value of the infinite sums (for the purpose of correct rounding, approximate the value until its fourth decimal place does not change with further iterations.)**

Comment: this is not a well-defined problem at the moment -- slow-converging series may stabilize at the 4th decimal for a long time before eventually "destabilizing" again

Comment: @MichaelChirico I'm thinking of having two parameters. One that would define what is stable and a timeout that would stop after x iterations. But the answer to the first one is pretty hard and not well defined in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a reasonable question, though it's only possible to answer it in a modified version, which is to create an algorithm that stops after producing *n* consecutive elements that are the same at the 4th decimal place. This of course does not give us logical certainty that the sequence has converged, but may be useful in some circumstances.

The following function will take a vector and compare the terminal *n* elements for equality in the 4th decimal place.

```r
fourth_decimal_stable <- function(vec, n)
{
  if(length(vec) < n) return(FALSE)
  fourth <- floor((vec * 1e4))
  all(diff(fourth[length(vec) + -(n - 1):0]) == 0)
}
```

Now, we can test it with a sequence that converges on pi (this is a version of the Leibniz series). This function grows the given vector by appending the next term in the series onto it (though the first term given to it must be zero:

```
nth_term <- function(vec)
{
  n <- length(vec) 
  c(vec, vec[n] + sqrt(12) * ((-1/3)^(n - 1)/(2 * (n - 1) + 1)))
}
```

Let's just confirm this works:

```
x <- 0
x <- nth_term(x)
x
[1] 0.000000 3.464102
x <- nth_term(x)
x
[1] 0.000000 3.464102 3.079201
x <- nth_term(x)
x
[1] 0.000000 3.464102 3.079201 3.156181
x <- nth_term(x)
x
[1] 0.000000 3.464102 3.079201 3.156181 3.137853
```

So let's find out how long this sequence is before it has 10 consecutive values that are the same at the 4th decimal. Our `while` loop also contains a term to ensure that the loop stops after 1000 iterations if the sequence doesn't converge by then

```
x <- 0
while(!fourth_decimal_stable(x, 10) & length(x) < 1000) x <- nth_term(x)
x
#>  [1] 0.000000 3.464102 3.079201 3.156181 3.137853 3.142605 3.141309 3.141674
#>  [9] 3.141569 3.141600 3.141591 3.141593 3.141592 3.141593 3.141593 3.141593
#> [17] 3.141593 3.141593
```

So we know that after 18 steps this algorithm has produced an answer that has been stable in the 4th decimal place for 10 consecutive terms. (In this case, element 10 is shown as having a 6 in the 4th decimal place, but this is due to rounding)