# Finding the value of infinite sums in r

Tags: r

I'm very new to r and programming so please stay with me :)

I am trying to use iterations to find the value of infinite iterations to the 4th decimal place. I.e. where the 4th decimal does not change. so 1.4223, where 3 does not change anymore so the result to 3 decimal place is 1.422.

[image]

The link above shows an example of a similar problem that I am faced with. My question is how do I create a for-loop that goes to infinity and find the value where the 4th decimal point stops changing?

I have tried using while loops but I am not sure how to stop it from just looping forever. I need some if statement like below:

```
result <- 0
i <- 1
d <- 1e-4
while(TRUE)
{
    result <- result + (1/(i^2))
    if(abs(result) < d)
    {
        break
    }
    i <- i + 1

}
result
```

Comment: can you give your actual code?  It shouldn't be much longer than the schematic version you have here, and will be easier to diagnose/use as the basis for an answer.

Comment: @BenBolker The problem is I dont know how to code it. I dont know how to iterate to infinity or the trick with it. So i gave the template I would use but cant effectively add the code. i.e how do i stop at 4th decimal i have no idea at all

Comment: @Willdomybest18 did you not try the answer I gave the last time you asked this question?

Comment: @AllanCameron, answered before I looked at history/dupes. Should this be closed as a duplicate?

Comment: @BenBolker the last question was closed because it was unfocused. This one is more specific and so I think should be left open, especially since you have given a clear answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example: to do the infinite loop, use `while(TRUE) {}`, and as you suggested use an `if` clause and `break` to stop when necessary.

```
## example equation shown
## fun <- function(x,n) {
##     (x-1)^(2*n)/(n*(2*n-1))
## }
## do it for f(x)=1/x^2 instead
## doesn't have any x-dependence, but leave it in anyway
fun <- function(x,n) {
     1/n^2
}

n <- 1
## x <- 0.6
tol <- 1e-4
ans <- 0
while (TRUE) {
   next_term <- fun(x,n)
   ans <- ans + next_term
   if (abs(next_term)<tol) break
   n <- n+1
}
```

When run this gives `ans=1.635082`, `n=101`.

- R also has a rarely used `repeat { }` keyword, but `while(TRUE)` will probably be clearer to readers
- there are more efficient ways to do this (i.e. calculating the numerator by multiplying it by `(x-1)^2` each time)
- it's generally a good idea to test for a maximum number of iterations as well so that you don't set up a truly infinite loop if your series doesn't converge or if you have a bug in your code
- I haven't solved your exact problem (chose a smaller value of `tol`), but you should be able to adjust this to get an answer
- as discussed in the [answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61555779/4th-decimal-of-an-infinite-sums-in-r), this isn't guaranteed, but should generally be OK; you can check (I haven't) to be sure that the particular series you want to evaluate has well-behaved convergence

Comment: what does 1e-6 do? Also what is```x <- 0.6```

Comment: 1e-6 is the tolerance that tells you when to stop. You probably want to set that to 1e-4 if you only want 4 digits of accuracy.  0.6 is the value I chose for x, you can pick whatever you want.

Comment: I tried using the code and updated the question but still doesnt finish. It just runs on forever.

Comment: did you use my code, or yours?  the code you posted doesn't make any sense (sorry ...) you shouldn't use `abs(result)`, but `abs(next_term)` (or the equivalent) ... you can use `cat()` statements to print out intermediate results and see what's going on

Comment: I used yours for a question ```1/i^2```

Comment: in your case `abs(next_term)` would be `abs(1/i^2)`

Comment: while you are encouraged to edit your question, it's not a good idea to edit to include the answer to the question.  If you want to post your own answer to the question (i.e. if you have some points to make that aren't included in the other answers), you can do that

Comment: Sorry I just need to show the code. Will take note. However, the loop still doesnt break. Even after fixing the problem stated above